# Nodemon not working and displaying "command not found" error

Tags: node.js, express, backend, nodemon

When I am trying to run my express server with the command 'nodemon solution.js' it gives an error message

C:\Users\anura\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

I've looked up all the solutions on stackoverlflow and reddit but nothing seems to fix it. The only solution that works is if I add a start script in the package.json file but its a hassle. Does anyone has any solution for this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypRcN.png)

Tried adding the path of nodemon to system variables it still doesnt works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm uninstall nodemon` and `npm install nodemon`.

Comment: I tried doing all of that it still gives the same error message.

Comment: Also check to see if everything is configured correctly and that you're in the proper directory when running `nodemon solution.js`.